# Python equivalent of MATLAB's Legendre function

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, polynomials

Currently, I am trying to analyze time series data with Python. As a guideline for doing so, I oriented myself on a MATLAB script that does pretty much everything I'd like to do. So far it worked fine, but now I bumped into this Legendre polynomial that was used in that script.

I tried the [NumPy implementation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.legendre.html) of it, but I couldn't find a way that (more or less) yielded the same results as [the MATLAB function](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legendre.html).

Basically, this is what I'd like to know. How can I make my Python code give the same results as the MATLAB code?

As a small demonstration,

```
    k= [0 1 1;1 1 0 ;0 0 1]
    legendre(2,k)
```

gives:

```
ans(:,:,1) =

-0.5000    1.0000   -0.5000
0         0         0
3.0000         0    3.0000


ans(:,:,2) =

1.0000    1.0000   -0.5000
     0         0         0
     0         0    3.0000


ans(:,:,3) =

1.0000   -0.5000    1.0000
     0         0         0
     0    3.0000         0
```

Whereas my Python version of it goes like this: the way I tried it goes like so:

```
    legendre = np.polynomial.legendre.Legendre([0,1,2])
    legendre(k)
```

And yields:

```
   array([[-1.,  3.,  3.],
   [ 3.,  3., -1.],
   [-1., -1.,  3.]])
```

I see a few things that are a bit weird, but unfortunately I have no clue about how to test for them, because this is the first time I heard of such a thing like Legendre polynomial and neither NumPy's documentation nor Wikipedia are a big help understanding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and was successful with building the following:

```
from scipy import special

def legendre(n,X) :
res = []
for m in range(n+1):
    res.append(special.lpmv(m,n,X))
return res
```

For my applications this works very well - maybe some of you can use this too.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this problem as well. Used this question as a starting point and came up with the following. Please note: I'm using the MATLAB function like so:

```
legendre(10,linspace(-1,1,10))
```

And I needed to generate the equivalent in Python. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import special as sp

def legendre(N,X) :
    matrixReturn = np.zeros((N+1,X.shape[0]))
    for i in enumerate(X) :
        currValues = sp.lpmn(N,N,i[1])
        matrixReturn[:,i[0]] = np.array([j[N] for j in currValues[0]])
    return matrixReturn
```

I'm very new to Python, so I'm sure the above could be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, well I think you will have trouble replicating these reslults using this module, as judging by the name only deals with the legendre polynomials (These are the solutions to the legendre equation where mu = 0, otherwise known as order 0 solutions)

I don't know matlab, but looking at the documentation, your input is calculating the results of the legendre functions of up to the order of the degree specified.

In python, what you seem to be doing is creating a composition of the zeroeth first and second order legendre polynomials

0*l_0 + 1*l_1 + 2*l_2

you can evaluate the legendre polynomials at the points specified:

```
l0 = np.polynomial.legendre.Legendre([0,1])
```

and you can verify that

```
l0(0.5) == 0.5
```

I hope this is useful - feel free to ask more questions

Edit:

```
def coefficients(order):
    for i in range(1, order):
         base = np.zeros(order)
         base[i] = 1
         yield base

def a(n, m):
    return 1.0*(2*n+1) / ((n*(n+1))**m)

def g(const_dist, m, order):
     legendres = [np.polynomial.legendre.Legendre(n) for n in coefficients(order)]
     terms = [a(n+1,m)*legendres[n](const_dist) for n,_ in enumerate(legendres)]
     return sum(terms)


>>> g(0.4, 4, 6)
0.073845698737654328
```

I hope this works for you, let me know if I have messed something up

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now a bit better. So, in order to mimic matlab's legendre in python, I own't be able to use this module, but would have to write my own legendre function? Do you think it would be sufficient (and doable) to put Rodrigues formula (see wiki) into python, so that I can create the polynomials separately and evaluate each of them at specified points? Btw. the formula I actually have to translate is the first one on slide 14 in this [pdf](http://jallen.faculty.arizona.edu/sites/jallen.faculty.arizona.edu/files/Chapter_22_Surface_Laplacian.pdf). Any ideas how to do it else?

Comment: actually, I think the python module is sufficient here, as you only appear to be calculating legendre polynomials, not legendre functions. I will try to add a possible calculation of this function to my answer

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose "order" to be "6" and "m" to be "4"? Isn't the normal case that you take every polynomial up to the last one, or don't I get anything?

Comment: Forget my last comment, it was a silly question. I just had a look on the actual formula and saw that "m" is completely unrelated.Sorry

Answer (score 2):

@user3684792 Thanks for the code, but this is not exactly what is needed, e.g. `cosdist` is normally a matrix, so that `sum(terms)` would not suffice (easy fix though).

Based on your comment and [this](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/legendre_polynomial/legendre_polynomial.html) definition of Legrande polynomials, I tried it myself. What I ended up with is this code. May I ask for your opinion about it?

```
    def P(n,x):
        if n == 0:
            return  1
        elif n==1:
            return  x
        elif n>1:
            return  (2*n-1)/n * x * P(n-1,x) - (n-1)/n * P(n-2,x)

    #some example data
    order = 4
    cosdist= np.array(((0.4,0.1),(-0.2,0.3)))
    m = 3
    dim1_cosdist, dim2_cosdist = cosdist.shape

    Gf = np.zeros((order, dim1_cosdist, dim2_cosdist))
    for n in range(1,order):
        Gf[n] = 1.0*(2*n+1) / ((n*(n+1))**m) * P(n,cosdist) 

    G = np.sum(Gf,axis = 0)
```

In case of cosdist is just an integer, this script gives the same results as yours. 
What irritates me, is that these results are still somewhat different than those resulting from the Matlab code, i.e. the resulting array has even different dimensions.
Thanks.
Edit: By accident, I confused `m` with `order`. Now it should be correct

Comment: Nice use of the recurrence relation. This is a super simple way to get them that is probably nicer for your use.  (It may be slower though, so you should profile this if speed is important).

Comment: I agree that it is probably nicer to calculate this with codistance as a matrix, but given a matrix is just a set of coefficients, (i.e numbers) you can actually calculate Gij, by running the equation for each of the codistance Ij numbers.

Comment: wrt dimensionality, you can sanity check by making sure that Gij has the same dimensions as Codistance ij. You note that the dimensions are different to your matlab code. I remember when I looked through that function the first time seeing that it also calculates legendre functions, so this might be what you are also seeing there (which if so, is not what you want to see).

Comment: Computation time isn't really important. The arrays I have to deal with are of size 128 x 128, and only computeted once, but I will keep this in mind, thanks. Btw. Shall I close this topic somehow? Or what is the best way to deal with it now, since I am finished here and the actual (original) question wasn't answered?

Comment: I guess just leave it open if you don't think the original q was answered, maybe it will help someone else. The answer to this was that matlab was giving legendre fn solutions too I think, which is not what you wanted

Answer (score 2):

[SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) has the [associated Legendre polynomials](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.lpmn.html#scipy.special.lpmn). It isn't the same as the MATLAB version, but it should provide most of what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import lpmv

def legendre(deg,x):
    return np.asarray([lpmv(i,deg,x) for i in range(deg+1)])

x=np.array([[0,1,1],[1,1,0],[0,0,1]])
legendre(2,x)
```

it gives what you want.